# Updating Postgres 9.5 Jsonb by id

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I've read the docs and stack, but I'm too dumb to get this without asking my specific question.

Say I have an array of objects stored in a jsonb column, e.g.

```
[{"id":1, "value":"a"], {"id":2, "value":"b"}]
```

What is the most efficient way to change index 1's value from "b" to "c" if you don't have the index and must search by id=2?

To be more specific, I'm writing a react/redux/node real time app, and I don't want to trust the redux state to give the index to update value. Rather, I want the client to send id=2 and let the server/database find the index of that array, and then update the value.

I'm currently using logic to return the index (e.g. select the entire jsonb column, use a lodash function to find the index with id=2, then update jsonb_set with the lodash found index).

My hope is there's a one query, no server logic way to accomplish this.  I've tried to use sub queries, but the postgres docs don't show how to return an index.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:  Here's the current database queries and logic using Node.

```
let _ = require('lodash');
let id=2;
let newValue='c';
let query=`SELECT jsonb_column from table where rowid=1`;
pgQuery(query)
.then((result)=>{
    result=result[0].result // cleaning up the return object
    //result=[{"id":1, "value":"a"], {"id":2, "value":"b"}];
    let index=_.findLastIndex(result, {id}) // index=1
    let query2=`UPDATE table
               SET jsonb_column=jsonb_set(jsonb_column, '{${index}, value}', '${newValue}') 
               WHERE rowid=1` RETURNING jsonb_column

    return pgQuery(query2) 
    // returns [{"id":1, "value":"a"], {"id":2, "value":"c"}];
})
```

Can that be reduced to one postgres query?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense: "What is the most efficient way...". Can you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish, what you're doing and why it is failing?

Comment: How do you change "value":"b" to "value":c" when you have id=2 and no index?   What I'm doing isn't failing, thus my question "what is the most efficient way."  My way may be the only way.  That's what I'm hoping someone can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table a_table (rowid int, jsonb_column jsonb);
insert into a_table values (1, '[{"id":1, "value":"a"}, {"id":2, "value":"b"}]');
insert into a_table values (2, '[{"id":2, "value":"a"}, {"id":1, "value":"b"}]');
```

You have two options. The first (somewhat complicated), use `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) with ordinality`:

```
update a_table t1
set jsonb_column = 
        jsonb_set(
            jsonb_column, 
            array[(
                select ordinality::int- 1
                from a_table t2, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) with ordinality
                where t1.rowid = t2.rowid and value->>'id' = '2')::text,
            'value'::text],
            '"c"'
        );

select * from a_table;

 rowid |                    jsonb_column                    
-------+----------------------------------------------------
     1 | [{"id": 1, "value": "a"}, {"id": 2, "value": "c"}]
     2 | [{"id": 2, "value": "c"}, {"id": 1, "value": "b"}]
(2 rows)
```

The second option (a bit simpler), modify values in consecutive json elements and aggregate the result:

```
update a_table t1
set jsonb_column = (
    select jsonb_agg(val)
    from (
        select case 
            when value->'id' = '2' then jsonb_set(value, '{value}', '"d"')
            else value end val
        from a_table t2, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column)
        where t1.rowid = t2.rowid
        ) s
    );

select * from a_table;

 rowid |                    jsonb_column                    
-------+----------------------------------------------------
     1 | [{"id": 1, "value": "a"}, {"id": 2, "value": "d"}]
     2 | [{"id": 2, "value": "d"}, {"id": 1, "value": "b"}]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Absolutely genius, thank you!  I found your first example a little easier (probably because that's similar to the query I tried to write).  I have some research to do on ordinality.  And for anyone else looking at my question and the answer, klin answered a harder question of modifying all rows.  My question assumes you know the row id.  Simply add a where rowid=

Comment: i need delete query by id for same data in this example.