# PostgreSQL Query n Manipulate JSON data

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nosql

I have problem with update jsonb type in postgree,

this is my example json

```
{
  "total": 2, 
  "products":[
        {"name": "guitar", "price": 100000, "brand": "yamaha"},
        {"name": "guitar", "price": 100000, "brand": "kramer"}
   ]
}
```

and this is my script, following answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215029/3073003)

```
update product_map t1
set data = (
    select jsonb_agg(val)
    from (
        select case
            when value->>'brand' = 'yamaha' then jsonb_set(value, '{price}', '3200')
            else value end val
        from product_map t2, jsonb_array_elements(data->'products')
        where t1.merchant = t2.merchant
        and t2.merchant like '0002%'
    ) s
)
where t1.merchant like '0002%';
```

there is no error, but my json changed to

```
[
    {"name": "guitar", "price": 3200, "brand": "yamaha"},
    {"name": "guitar", "price": 100000, "brand": "kramer"}
]
```

I want to update the data in this case is "price", 
but I don't want to change the json format.

Comment: [Consider normalizing the data](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=database+normalization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=xduhV_r9H8SFwgT65KyIDA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are replacing whole json object to json array so you are getting such result.

Please try this

```
 update product_map t1
    set data = (
        select json_build_object('total',data#>>'{total}','products',jsonb_agg(val))
        from (
            select data, 
case when value->>'brand' = 'yamaha' then jsonb_set(value, '{price}', '3200')
                else value end val
            from product_map t2, jsonb_array_elements(data->'products')
            where t1.merchant = t2.merchant
            and t2.merchant like '0002%'
        ) s )where t1.merchant like '0002%';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when I run the your script I get error like this, 
"ERROR:  column "s.produk" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3:  select json_build_object('total',produk#>>'{total}','produc..."...

and I try to add "group by s.produk" in the inner query "select data...", and it's work, 
I hope this is correct, but if you have an opinion for this error please inform me again..thanks again..