# PostgresSQL nested jsonb update value of complex key/value pairs

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Starting out with JSONB data type and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have a table (**properties**) with two columns (**id** as primary key and **data** as jsonb).
The **data** structure is:

```
    {
        "ProductType": "ABC",
        "ProductName": "XYZ",
        "attributes": [
            {
            "name": "Color",
            "type": "STRING",
            "value": "Silver"
            },
            {
            "name": "Case",
            "type": "STRING",
            "value": "Shells"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

I would like to update the **value** of a specific **attributes** element by **name** for a row with a given **id**. For example, for the element with *"name"="Case"* change the value to *"Glass"*. So it ends up like

```
    {
        "ProductType": "ABC",
        "ProductName": "XYZ",
        "attributes": [
            {
            "name": "Color",
            "type": "STRING",
            "value": "Silver"
            },
            {
            "name": "Case",
            "type": "STRING",
            "value": "Glass"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Is this possible with this structure using SQL?

I have created table structure if any of you would like to give it a shot.
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e05b3ae61e453eb7a6896e45627b753)

Comment: Looks like there was a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194234/updating-postgres-9-5-jsonb-by-id

Answer (score 1):

Use the jsonb concatenation operator, `||`, to replace keys on the fly:

```
WITH properties (id, data) AS (
  values 
    (1, '{"ProductType": "ABC","ProductName": "XYZ","attributes": [{"name": "Color","type": "STRING","value": "Silver"},{"name": "Case","type": "STRING","value": "Shells"}]}'::jsonb), 
    (2, '{"ProductType": "ABC","ProductName": "XYZ","attributes": [{"name": "Color","type": "STRING","value": "Red"},{"name": "Case","type": "STRING","value": "Shells"}]}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT id,
       data||
       jsonb_build_object(
         'attributes',
         jsonb_agg(
           case 
             when attribs->>'name' = 'Case' then attribs||'{"value": "Glass"}'::jsonb
             else attribs
           end
         )
       ) as data
  FROM properties m
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data->'attributes') as a(attribs)
 GROUP BY id, data
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2ba7be5b147994c343464928020b8600)

Comment: I realize now I forgot to mention that if there are multiple rows then is there a way to target a specific row by id? Sorry, I will update question.